Unexpected Double Network Traffic on Writes in a 2-Node S2D Cluster with Nested Mirror-Accelerated Parity
Full disclosure: I work for StarWind, but the research below is unrelated to my company's activities.
I'm currently exploring the I/O data path in Microsoft Storage Spaces Direct (S2D) for a series of blog posts.
I’ve encountered an odd behavior with doubled network traffic during write operations in a 2-node S2D cluster configured with Nested Mirror-Accelerated Parity (MAP).
During write tests, something unexpected happened: While writing at 1 GiB/s, network traffic to the partner node was constantly at 2 GiB/s instead of the expected 1 GiB/s.
Could this be due to S2D configuring the mirror storage tier with four data copies (NumberOfDataCopies = 4), where S2D writes two data copies on the local node and another two on the partner node?
Setup details:
The environment is a 2-node S2D cluster running Windows Server 2022 Datacenter 21H2 (OS build 20348.2527). I followed Microsoft’s resiliency options for nested configurations as outlined here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/nested-resiliency#resiliency-options
... and created a nested mirror-accelerated parity volume with the following commands:
New-StorageTier -StoragePoolFriendlyName s2d-pool -FriendlyName NestedPerformance -ResiliencySettingName Mirror -MediaType SSD -NumberOfDataCopies 4

New-StorageTier -StoragePoolFriendlyName s2d-pool -FriendlyName NestedCapacity -ResiliencySettingName Parity -MediaType SSD -NumberOfDataCopies 2 -PhysicalDiskRedundancy 1 -NumberOfGroups 1 -FaultDomainAwareness StorageScaleUnit -ColumnIsolation PhysicalDisk -NumberOfColumns 4

New-Volume -StoragePoolFriendlyName s2d-pool -FriendlyName Volume01 -StorageTierFriendlyNames NestedPerformance, NestedCapacity -StorageTierSizes 820GB, 3276GB

A test VM was created on this volume and specifically hosted on the node that owns the volume, avoiding any I/O redirection (as ReFS volumes always operate in File System Redirected Mode).
Testing approach:
Inside the VM, I ran tests with 1M read and 1M write patterns, setting up controls to cap performance at 1 GiB/s and limit network traffic to a single cluster network. The goal was to monitor network interface utilization.
During read tests, the network interfaces stayed quiet, confirming that reads were handled locally.
However, once again, during write tests, while writing at 1 GiB/s, I observed that network traffic to the partner node consistently reached 2 GiB/s instead of anticipated 1 GiB/s.
Any ideas on why this doubled traffic is occurring on write workloads?
For more background, here’s a link to my blog article with a full
breakdown:
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/microsoft-s2d-data-locality
Would greatly appreciate any insights!

Is this different from the known limitations of FileSystemRedirected mode? https://web.archive.org/web/20201022101422/https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/issues/2051

These two seem to be totally unrelated.

You set up your test VM to write a specific data pattern which is easy to do with FIO tweaks. Install WireShark from the link below and analyze the traffic, whether it’s incoming (destination) or outgoing (source). If you spot the same pattern appearing twice but with different timestamps, it means Microsoft isn’t optimizing things on the source side. Instead of calculating hashes and sending minimal metadata, it’s pushing the same data twice. This not only hammers your network bandwidth but also forces the destination CPU to compare the two streams to ensure they match. Honestly, I’d file a bug report with Microsoft—looks like someone over there isn’t taking their job seriously. Just my $0.02, of course!
P.S. WireShark is here:
https://www.wireshark.org
